# Okta blocks call from angular front end at localhost:4200 to spring boot backend at localhost:8080

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, cors, okta

When Okta is used to secure API access, cross domain call from angular app at localhost:4200 to spring boot app at localhost:8080 will be blocked even with @CrossOrigin("*") placed on controller.

Below is the error in developer console:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at http://localhost:8080/api/messages from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

Here is the code of the angular app which makes a GET request to backend with an access token in headers.

```
getMessages(): Observable<Message[]>{
      const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/messages';
      const accessToken = this.oktaAuth.getAccessToken();
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200'});
      return this.http.get<Message[]>(apiUrl, {headers: headers});
  }
```

Both front end and backend are integrated with Okta authentication.

If spring boot Okta starter dependency is removed from POM, cross domain call can be made with @CrossOrigin("*") placed at the controller. But if spring boot Okta starter is included in POM, @CrossOrigin("*") will not work. Looks like OKta is responding to the preflight request from browser.

Tried to enable CORS by following https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/enable-cors/main/
and have http://localhost:4200 listed in Trusted Origins ( type CORS ). But this does not work.  Okta said Trusted Origins config does not work for OAuth2. This seems to be a common scenario.  But I could not find a working solution on Internet. Anyone has a solution for this?  Thanks

Tried to enable CORS by following https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/enable-cors/main/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, `@CrossOrigin` stops working when you integrate it with Spring Security. Adding a filter works much better. Can you try registering a CORS filter and see if that works?

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean simpleCorsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

Comment: We figured out a solution for this issue. In addition to adding the CorsConfigurationSource, we add an oauth2ResourceServer().jwt() filter to Security filter chain.

Comment: @Jry - I am also facing same problem but the solution you mentioned i.e. adding CorsConfigurationSource and adding oauth2ResourceServer().jwt() filter to Security filter chain did't help me. so wondering if anything else needs to be udpated.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring an Angular app as a (public) OAuth2 client is not considered a best practice anymore. This applies to all Javascript based frameworks. If you have a look at Gmail, Facebook, Linkedin, Github, etc., with your browser debugging tools, you won't find a single request with a `Bearer` token in an `Authorization` header (you'll just find session cookies).

The reason for this is the BFF pattern: the (confidential) OAuth2 client is a middleware on the server in charge of hiding tokens from the browser and Javascript code. Requests between the browser and this middleware are secured with sessions (and protection against CSRF). The BFF replaces the session cookie with the OAuth2 token in session before forwarding a request to downstream resource-server.

Now your CORS point: if this middleware is used to proxy both your Angular app and your REST API, then, from the browser point of view, all requests will have the same origin, and abracadabra, your CORS error will be gone.

`spring-cloud-gateway` can be used as BFF if you configure it as an OAuth2 client and add the `TokenRelay=` filter when routing to your Spring resource server(s). I wrote [a complete tutorial on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).